# How check bitArray contains any true or any false value?

Tags: c#, vb.net

In C# and Vb.net,is any way without iterating by loop a bitarray to check contins any true or false value (Dotnet 2.0) ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I doubt there's any way you could do it without a loop under the hood (as a `BitArray` can be arbitrarily long, unlike `BitVector32`), but if you just don't want to write it yourself:

```
var hasAnyTrue = input.Cast<bool>().Contains(true);
var hasAnyFalse = input.Cast<bool>().Contains(false);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the BitArray class from System.Collections you can use the following code to determine if anything is true.

C# version

```
var anyTrue = myArray.Cast<bool>().Any(x => x);
```

VB.Net Version

```
Dim anyTrue = myArray.Cast(Of Boolean)().Any(Function(x) x)
```

Comment: Any advantage in not going with the simpler `.Contains(true)` instead of `Any`? Actually, this is the way I had done that initially, but `Contains` came to mind and I changed it as I couldn't find any specific reason. Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you can do it using a BitArray, but if you use an int, long etc. and then check to see if it is greater than 0 (for true) or less than the max value of the data type (for false) that would do it.

so something like this:

```
bool IsTrue (int bitArray)
{
  return bitArray != 0;
}


bool isFalse (int bitArray)
{
   return bitArray != int.MinValue;
}
```

Comment: Indeed, that was going to be my suggestion too assuming it casts ok.

Comment: BitArray is a type. It isn't an `int`.

Comment: Yeah, but like you said there really isn't a way of checking the values without doing a loop.  I was just offering a way of checking an array of bits, not necessarily using the BitArray type.

Comment: Even in that case, it isn't right. `int` is a signed type. hasFalse should check `!= int.MinValue` and hasTrue should check ` != 0`.

Comment: Good point, I didn't think that through.  Thanks for catching it.

Answer (score 2):

Indexing into the `BitArray` and checking the individual `boolean` values is an obvious solution. If you are concerned about performance, you should first and foremost consider creating your own abstraction, but if you prefer using `BitArray` for most of your operations, then you could do the check using `CopyTo` to an `int[]` of the right size (`Count >> 5`), and then perform zero or non-zero checks on these ints as appropriate.